# How to set two address in ”access_control_allow_origin”?

Tags: cors

I want set **two address** in access_control_allow_origin, but don't know how.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:address
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: address
```

In this case, only the finish line is working.

`access_control_allow_origin=*` this it work for all address

But I just want to set two addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can “want” all day long, it is not possible.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin:

> `<origin>`
>   Specifies an origin. **Only a single origin can be specified.**

You need to do this in a dynamic way: Check what `Origin` the client send in the request headers, and then respond back with that value - after you have determined whether it is one of those you want to allow to begin with. (If you just respond with the request origin without doing any check, that would practically result in the same as if you had specified `*` to begin with.)